# persisting and restoring data in data structures

Tags: data-structures

I am new to data structures and understood that data structures like lists, stacks, queues, trees and etc are supposed to be accessed in-memory, there are [some suggestions](https://www.quora.com/How-can-a-linked-list-or-tree-data-structure-be-saved-in-memory-permanently-as-a-database) on how to persist data structures in database.

so questions are:

1. to persist a data structure, one has to destructure and save to database in a way that is most efficient for later restructuring?
2. to restore the data of the data structures, one has to read from the database and then reconstruct the data structures again on when the system is up after reboot/failure?
3. is this common practice, or is there a proper way that one can prevent the reconstruction of the data structures (as they consume compute power)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. It depends on the data structure
   For structures such as lists, stacks, queues, trees... they are usually implemented with pointers (pointer to next node, to children etc.)
   These pointers which exist only in memory contain information about the data structure, so you will need an efficient way to convert this structure information
   For instance checkout the tree serialization on leetcode:
   https://leetcode.com/faq/#binary-tree
   For data structure which can be implemented in a contiguous memory segment without pointers such as string, binary heap etc. you do not need this process and can just save the bits of the memory segment in database
2. Yes
3. Yes it is very common practice, historically XML has been the format of choice for this, JSON is popular more recently
   A lot of services work by fetching persisted XML data in a database, build the data structure in memory, perform some operation then save back the result

If you think about it the whole web works like this:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Document_Object_Model
Every HTML page is actually a serialized tree data structure, which gets reconstructed in memory by your browser

Comment: thank you for pointing out the fact that some data structures rely on pointers, that didn't actually cross my mind when i was thinking about the whole question